# Castle Windsor not resolving when build configuration is "AnyCPU" or "x64"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, build, castle-windsor, 32bit-64bit

I am using CastleWindsor to register and resolve NHibernate dependencies in a console app and everything works fine as long as I build in x86 platform. But if I change this platform to "AnyCPU" or "x64" it stops resolving the components. Is there a CastleWindsor issue that I am not aware of or am I doing something wrong? Help please.
Here is some code that I am using (nothing fancy):

Registration Code:

```
container.Register(Component.For<ILogger>()
.ImplementedBy<Log4netLog>(),
Component.For<Repository.INHibUnitOfWork>()
.ImplementedBy<Repository.NHibUnitOfWork>().LifestyleTransient()....
```

Resolve code:

```
    _windsorContainer = new WindsorContainer();
        _windsorContainer.Install(FromAssembly.This());
        _windsorContainer.Resolve<ISessionFactory>();
```

Getting an error on the last line. No component for supporting the service ISessionFactory was found. The code runs fine if I build it in x86 configuration.

Comment: Could you post the exact error message ? Preferably including the inner exception(s) as well ? And can you try to register the component manually instead of using FromAssemblyThis ? I expect that your executing directory is missing a 64 bits dll.

Comment: Most likely you're doing something wrong. Hard do say with the level of details you've provided

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. One of the project (in the list of 20 projects) was set to build using x86 configuration. After changing its build settings I was able to build and run the project using ANYCPU setting. Thanks for following up and pointing me to the right direction.